# C# Share listview items across pages

Tags: c#, list, class, model-view-controller, uwp

Beginner here.

I have a list on my MainPage that I am adding items to by typing stuff into a textbox submitting it. After creating a listview item, I would like to be able to click on an item and see its value in another page.

I created a DetailsPage for this, but I don't know what the best way is to share that data across these pages.

This is what I have in my MainPage so far:
     public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public int itemCounter;

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();


    //This is the button that submits the entered text

    public void btnSubmitInPopup_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Create new listview item and textblock
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        TextBlock txtBloodSugarValue = new TextBlock();


        //Save text input value to label and add item to list
        txtBloodSugarValue.Text = txtInput.Text;
        item.Content = txtBloodSugarValue;
        mainListView.Items.Add(item);


        //Reset text input field
        txtInput.Text = "";

        //Update counter of items in list
        itemCounter = mainListView.Items.Count();
        lblItemCounter.Text = itemCounter.ToString();


    }
}
```

My DetailPage literally has just one label that I am trying to populate with whatever value is in the listview item that I clicked on in my MainPage.

What's the best way to do this? 
Hope this makes sense.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 way to do that:

1. declaring static variable and set that in first form and use in second form(or anywhere!)
2. Create public field/propeey inside second form class and set it from first form
3. Pass value as parameter to constructor/function of second class

I add second form class here:

```
public static int StaticVariable { get; set; }//First Method
public int PublicProperty { get; set; }

public Form2(int Value)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //Do your code here with constructor way here
}
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    //Do your code for 1,2 here
}

public void SetValueWithFunction(int value)
{
    //Do your code for setting value with second type in Number 3
}
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I replied to your comment above with code.

Comment: @Liz4112 I've added full code above and I hope you can use that